# Multiple references separated by semi-colon

Tags: hyperref, bibtex, formatting, preamble

The following is in the preamble I "inherited":

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt} % for upper line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt} % for lower line
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\itshape \nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\numberwithin{equation}{section} % numbering according to the section
\bibliographystyle{plain} %Choose a bibliograhpic style

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=black{hyperref}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

%\parindent0em
\parskip1ex
```

In my .tex file, for each reference I state, for instance: `"as reported in \citep{schum98,berg90,tom90}"`. The pdf output "`[Schuman, 1998, Berg, 1990, Tomaven, 1990]`". As you may notice, such a listing is awkward. How could I separate the data belonging to a specific author by a semi-colon from the data belonging to other authors, as in "`[Schuman, 1998; Berg, 1990; Tomaven, 1990]`".
Note that a large portion of the .tex document has been written, and I would prefer the option of just changing the preamble.

Comment: With that preamble you won't get an author-year citation scheme.

Comment: I solved it by adding `\usepackage[semicolon]{natbib}`. Thanks for pointing out the missing `natbib`.

Comment: @boy: once the software allows you to do so, you should post your resolution (the comment above) as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by adding `\usepackage[semicolon]{natbib}`. Thanks for pointing out the missing `natbib`.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the `cite` package, `nospace` option:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\def\citepunct{;\penalty\citepunctpenalty}
```

and `space` option:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\def\citepunct{;\penalty\citepunctpenalty}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
\def\citepunct{; \penalty\citepunctpenalty}
```

Comment: This answer has already been given by @Thomas Rebele.

Comment: Actually there is an extra space after the `;`. So it is not a duplicate if this has an influence.